# What is SPL exploit?

Tags: exploit

I recently worked on a web project that uses Javascript and PHP to load its content from flickr API.

I kept on getting this image show up and disappear immediately during first 2 or 3 seconds of the page load (`http://www.yceml.net/0355/10883427-2.jpg`) and couldn't find anything in the code that requests this image.

So I did google search on this image and came across this page: https://urlquery.net/report.php?id=1229289

So, obviously, it's a malware of some sort... can anyone please explain what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: There's not enough information to get us started. "SPL Exploit" is used  urlQuery to describe attacks that has the same signature, supposedly from an exploit kit called SPL Exploit Kit, usually they're websites hosting the [CVE-2012-1723](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-1723) exploit. We don't know whether the server hosting your web project is infected, or your own system is infected.

Comment: This looks like spyware.

Comment: To add to @Adnan's answer, here's an [in-depth analysis](http://ondailybasis.com/blog/?p=1774) from another guy asking the same question. It includes exploit kit removal procedure.